# Pop-Up window on parent window from iFrame button

Tags: javascript

If I have a button within a iframe, how can I create a pop-up window that will appear as part of the parent window and not within the iframe window, when I press on this button, within the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that you can, this is a protection from iframes taking over a parent page.  Meaning you couldn't have a floating div.  You could popup a new window from the browser like normal.